# DataSourceTransactionManager bean not created after Introducing Spring Batch @EnableBatchProcessing Annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am integrating Spring Batch in one of the existing applications where other beans are successfully using `DataSourceTransactionManager`. However, I am getting the following error when I introduce the `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation :

> Field transactionManager in AuthBeans required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager' that could not be found.

I've tried to configure `BatchConfigurer` but it has not resolved the issue. Please see `BatchConfigurer` code below.

```
@Configuration
public class CustomBatchConfigurer implements BatchConfigurer {


    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;


    @Override
    public JobRepository getJobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(getTransactionManager());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return  (JobRepository) factory.getObject();
    }

    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() throws Exception {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(getJobRepository());
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Override
    public JobExplorer getJobExplorer() throws Exception {
        JobExplorerFactoryBean factory = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return  (JobExplorer) factory.getObject();
    }
```

I am wondering am I missing something? Your help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of spring Batch are you using? Please post the full stacktrace of the exception. Otherwise, please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue to be able to help you in an efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

In which class , you kept `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation.
`@EnableBatchProcessing` should be at the highest level.

`@EnableBatchProcessing` will create the `DataSourceTransactionManager` by default.

Go through this [BatchConfigure](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/BatchConfigurer.html) and follow the [example](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-batch-javaconfig/blob/master/src/main/java/de/codecentric/batch/configuration/WebsphereInfrastructureConfiguration.java).

I hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: I have added @EnableBatchProcessing Annotation at the application level. I've already configured the BatchConfigurer  same as it is depicted in the example but it is not working.